# I am needing helping fixing an Excel code to convert fixture units to GPM

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to be able to calculate my total GPM (circled blue) from my total fixture units (circled in red) by going to conversion tables. That is for x number of fixtures, there is a corresponding GPM value. There are two conversion tables. One is for flush valves, and one is for flush tanks. They are both vertical and two column.

I have written a code, but am getting a spill error:

```
=IF($Q$7 = D11,VLOOKUP('GPM Table F 102'!A2:B89,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP('GPM Table F 102'!D2:E89,2,FALSE))
```

That code is referencing the table, but it does not know what cell total (circled red) to select I believe. So it wants to bring back all data and there is not enough room.

By the way, I am a mechanical engineer, and this is my first time to attempt to code in 3 years. Help is appreciated.

[Excel Total Supply and Total GPM Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WPfx.png)

[2 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYwtp.png)

Comment: The "code" is not VBA code but an Excel formula, right? You are missing the first parameter in both VLOOKUP-formulas: You need to specify *which* value you search as first parameter (eg Q11). The table *where* to look is the second parameter, the third parameter specifies which column should be returned and the 4th if VLookup look only for exact values (if it is set to FALSE) or find a "best match" (set it to TRUE). As you have a value of `0.7` in your data but not in your table, you should try `TRUE`.

Comment: I tried that and I still get the spill error. This code that I wrote works, but doesn't allow me to choose between flush valve or flush tank. I had to select one or the other tables for the VLOOKUP to search from. But there has to be a way I can choose a parameter and have it select from that corresponding table. =IF($Q11>=1,VLOOKUP($Q11,Flush_Valve,2))

Comment: What I believe is happening with the first code is that the VLOOKUP function is looking for F_V in the column to find the corresponding GPM, and in reality we need it to distinguish between F_V or F_T based on what the user enters, and then go to the respective table to find the corresponding GPM value on that respective table.

Comment: Hey there buddy, I'm thinking I need to make a function. Because my GPM will be a function of F_V (flush valve) or F_T(flush tank). Well at least you got me to thinking...